# Why does Geordi keep calling the Romulan officer "Commodore"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode [TNG: The Enemy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Enemy_(episode)), Geordi La Forge is marooned on a planet with a reticent Romulan. Geordi offers his own "*name and rank*" but the Romulan refuses to respond in kind.

> **BOCHRA:** *Name and rank.*
>
> **LAFORGE:** *Lieutenant Commander Geordi La Forge. I don't think I got yours?*
>
> **BOCHRA:** *A Romulan ship will arrive shortly. You will accompany me on board.*
>
> **LAFORGE:** *I don't think so. You see, we heard your message too and well, **the fleet's in, Commodore.** Sky's full of Federation ships.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The Enemy](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/155.htm)</sup></sub>

**Why does Geordi persist in calling him by this particular rank?**

Comment: Inspired by "[Why aren't there any commodores in Star Trek: The Next Generation and after?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156224/why-arent-there-any-commodores-in-star-trek-the-next-generation-and-after)

Comment: I always interpreted this episode as cold war enemies marooned together and forced to find the 'humanity' in each other. So, in that light, it's it's like saying "comrade". That or he's mocking him :D

Comment: [Similar question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/startrek/comments/5rrm8b/why_did_geordi_call_the_romulan_commodore_as_an/)

Comment: @NKCampbell - He was mocking him. Trying to get a reaction...

Comment: Plus it was pretty dark on the planet, so you could say that Geordie and Bochra were working the [nightshift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FrkEDe6Ljqs).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Well they've certainly found themselves in a funky situation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is addressed in the show's [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/155.txt), but seems to have gotten lost in the [final edit](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/155.htm).

In the earlier version Geordi first addressed him by an obviously low rank ("ensign") and then by an obviously high rank ("commodore") in order to get him to react. That being said, it's not especially clear whether the Romulan Star Empire actually *has* commodores.

> **BOCHRA:** *Your name and rank.*
>
> **GEORDI:** *Lieutenant Commander Geordi La Forge. I don't believe I caught yours... ?*
>
> **BOCHRA:** *A Romulan ship will arrive shortly... you will accompany me on board...*
>
> **GEORDI:** *Uh, I really don't think that's gonna happen, Ensign... or is it Commodore...*
>
> (a beat, Bochra doesn't react)
>
> *Yeah, see... we heard your message too... and well, the fleet's in, Commodore. Sky's full of Federation ships.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: The Enemy - Original Script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/155.txt)</sup></sub>

For the record, after the third repetition this tactic finally works and Bochra does indeed offer his correct rank.

Comment: There is Commodore "Oh!" from Star Trek Picard...;-')